# Using Unison to sync my desktop computer with a container in the cloud

Tags: container, cloud, unison

I'd like to use Unison to sync a directory between my desktop computer and a container that lives in the cloud. I have this kind of working with Unison, but the problem I'm seeing is that every time I spin up the container, it can have a different hostname and IP number, and sshd will be running on a different port number.

To make this mostly transparent to me, every time I spin up the container, I edit my ~/.ssh/config file like so:

```
Host pod
   User root
   Hostname 184.26.5.182
   Port 10666
```

I replace the IP number and port number accordingly.

Once I've done this, I can log into the container using `ssh pod`, etc. I can run scripts that rsync stuff around with no problem, even though they have the host alias "pod" hardwired into them. (If I knew how to make rsync do a bidirectional sync with deletions, then I'd just use that, but I'm pretty sure that that is not possible.)

My Unison config file looks like this:

```
root = /Users/me/path/to/dir
root = ssh://pod//path/to/dir
 
ignore = Path subdir1
ignore = Path subdir2
```

Unfortunately, this does not work great because every time I spin up the container, I get a different port number (the IP number doesn't usually change), and Unison considers this to be a fresh sync. Which is not at all what I want.

Is there a way to tell Unison to ignore the fact that the remote container seems to have changed to a different computer, and to just trust that my "pod" host alias can be relied on for host identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've determined an answer to my question, but it's a bit of a pain.

First, I changed the entry in my local `~/.ssh/config` file so that it looks like this:

```
Host pod
   User root
   SetEnv UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME=pod
   Hostname 184.26.5.182
   Port 10666
```

That's very easy, of course. But this won't work, however, unless `sshd` is configured in the container to allow the incoming `ssh` client to perform this `SetEnv` command. `sshd` is ***not*** configured to allow this by default. Consequently, I'll have to write a script that I can invoke on the container every time I spin it up, which does the following before I run unison on my desktop computer:

1. Add the line `AcceptEnv UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME` onto the end of the container's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
2. Tell the container's sshd to reload its config file by doing

```
kill -HUP `cat /var/run/sshd.pid`
```

---

***ALTERNATIVELY:***

And a bit more easily, I can just have a script modify `/root/.bashrc` in the container to have

```
export UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME=pod
```

placed at the ***top*** of `/root/.bashrc`. (It wasn't working when I placed it at the bottom of the `.bashrc` because it turns out that there is code in the `.bashrc` that exits early if the shell is not interactive.)

Unfortunately, I can't just edit the `.bashrc` once and be done with it since the root filesystem is reinitialized every time the container is started up. So this rewriting of `/root/.bashrc` has to either be done by a script that I either keep on the persistent filesystem that the cloud service provides. Or I can do the editing of the container's `.bashrc` via a local script on my desktop that uses `ssh` and `scp` to make the change.